# Want to access variable outside the loop

Tags: java

*I want to print all those number which is taken by input and print but problem is that the variable which is inside the loop can not be accessed outside of the loop. Why it is so*.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      int a = Sc.nextInt();
      
  }
 System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

*Showing error
" System.out.println(a);
^
symbol:   variable a
location: class Solution
1 error
"*

```
My Input is :
1
2
3
```

*Desired output*

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Just declare it out of the loop (before it)

Comment: Use array/list declare before for loop and add values in the array/list. Then print the array/list as you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays for this problem. Since you don't prompt the user about how many inputs the user will give, I've added a `final int ARRAY_SIZE` variable to declare the number of inputs the user can give.

I placed another `for` loop that will iterate over the array for printing.

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ARRAY_SIZE = 3;
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            a[i] = Sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Some Notes:

1. The convention of naming objects in Java should be in lowerCamelCase, meaning your `Scanner Sc` should instead be named `Scanner sc`.
2. Java has scopes of variables that differ on where they were declared, you can read more in https://www.javatpoint.com/scope-of-variables-in-java

Comment: But It is printing as in each step .. I want to print all those number after input.. as i have mentioned in my post as "Desired input" and "Desired output"

Comment: yes yes thank you ..Now ok but how can we access the variable outside

Comment: @SUDHANSHUSHEKHARSRIVASTAVA do you mean outside the `main` method? you can pass it through parameter to other methods, or put it as a class variable, meaning outside the `main` method.

Answer (score -2):

The variable which you are using in the for loop is only limited inside it.You cannot access that variable outside because it is a local variable and not an instance variable.I don't know what kind of output is needed but here's something which might help.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers do u want to enter???");
    int totalNumbers=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter numbers");
    while(totalNumbers>0) {
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
        totalNumbers--;
    }
```

Comment: U know I want to Enter input in each line by using enter key and the output should be in each line. Please check my input output format where I asked question

Comment: Make sure you read question correctly. OP posted a desired output, while your solution would look like:
```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```
since the input would be printed as well.